# The editor for Corona on Win32 platform

Tags: coronasdk

I look for some editor where I could work with Lua. I have a Win32. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post on setting up IntelliJ to work with Corona http://producerism.com/blog/how-to-develop-in-corona-sdk-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

The IntelliJ / Corona Tutorial is great because it's free.  However there is also a Corona-specific IDE now too (just came out a few weeks ago):

http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/CIDER/

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Notepad++
Not an IDE, but for a text editor, it is pretty awesome.
And lightweight as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the Eclipse Koneki project (http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/).  It has an active developer community and even supports integration with the Corona debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Sublime Text 2, it's awesome in Mac and it has Windows version.

You wont be disappointed

Answer (score 0):

I use **Sublime 2** with the following add-on for code completion. Works great! The add on is for textmate but works for sublime as well.

https://github.com/osadchuk/Corona-SDK.tmbundle

**Corona Complete** is also pretty decent.

**Krea** - For windows only -- never tried but looks great

http://www.native-software.com/index.php/en/

Answer (score 0):

I use [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/)

It is free and lightweight Lua IDE with code completion, syntax highlighting, remote debugger, code analyzer, live coding, and debugging support for several Lua engines.

it supports debugging for Löve 2D, Moai, Gideros, Marmalade Quick and Corona. Available for Mac/Windows/Linux [here](http://studio.zerobrane.com/download.html?not-this-time).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is free. I use it in corona. It has an easy way to go to a particular line also.